# Prove limit a-priory

Tags: calculus, limits

This's a convergent limit and it's fully understandable why it's so. But task is about to prove that with usage of determination. I really have no idea how to do it.
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[3]\frac{n+0.25}{8n+1} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: What does "determination" mean here?

Comment: @bof Definition. The answer to the question what does limit mean.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $8n < 8n+1$, so $$\frac{n+\frac{1}{4}}{8n+1} \ge \frac{n}{8n} + \frac{1}{32n} \ge \frac{1}{8}$$
So you have a lower bound of $\frac{1}{2}$ for the limit.
Now try to find a sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{\alpha}{n}$ such that $a_n \ge \frac{n+\frac{1}{4}}{8n+1} $ for all $n \ge 1$.

With the sequence $a_n$ we can find for all $\epsilon > 0$ an $N$, depending on $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$ and can be calculated if needed, such that $a_n - \frac{1}{8} < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. Then we have for all $n \le N$ $$| \frac{n + \frac{1}{4}}{8n +1} - \frac{1}{8} | =\frac{n + \frac{1}{4}}{8n +1} - \frac{1}{8} \le a_n - \frac{1}{8} < \epsilon$$ 
So we have $\frac{n + \frac{1}{4}}{8n +1}$ converges to $\frac{1}{8}$, then I would use the continuity of $x \mapsto x^\frac{1}{3}$ for the final result.

Comment: Do you mean prove it with Squeeze theorem? Cause I do not understand how comparison test provide proof via determination.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the squeeze theorem.

Comment: it's an awesome theorem and I got how you used it. Thank you for the solution. But the task requires usage of determination of the limit. As I understand you can use as determination with epsilon neighborhood as $\epsilon > |x_n - a|$.

Comment: Also I tried to use your conversion in the determination with $|x_n - a| < \epsilon$ but I coudn't canceled $\frac{1}{32n}$ out when it's under root.